# AJAX Only Javascript Library

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am searching for a Javascript Library Which has only AJAX no other feature. e.g. a Small Simple XMLHttp Wrapper.

Comment: I highly recommend [vapor.js](http://vaporjs.com/)

Comment: You really just want an XML Http Wrapper? Why not write one yourself? That would probably be faster than searching and waiting for answers here...

Comment: @Matt, as long as you use the compressed version

Comment: @Nick, I went to their github to check the source and it is empty 0 lines of code ?? Am I missing something??

Comment: @Matt Especially `=>` :P

Comment: If something already exists. Why would I take the overhead of maintanance ?

Comment: I wonder if the vapor.js guys are looking for help, it seems like a great project. I bet I could double the size, functionality, and speed of their code base with very little effort

Comment: @user: "maintenance?" Really? The only browser you have to adjust for is `!@#$%^&*ing IE`, and their release cycles aren't exactly _"speedy"_

Comment: @Nick I am wondering why no documentation besides small Getting Started is included.

Comment: Where is the documentations for vapor.js

Comment: Documentation is on GitHub: http://github.com/madrobby/vapor.js

Comment: @matt Support vapor.js on MSO! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53346/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2010/67974#67974

Comment: LOL vapor.js is empty I can get vapor.packed.js
But How can one understand from a compressed js.

Comment: @user: `vapor.packed.js` will actually yield worse performance (in most cases) than the regular `vapor.js`. However I can recommend two alternatives (1) check out [vapor.min.js](http://github.com/madrobby/vapor.js/blob/master/vapor.min.js) or (2) just include the following HTML snippet in your page:

Comment: @Matt Ball vapor.min.js is empty on your link.

Comment: @user you should really check out the [vapor.js performance graph](http://vaporjs.com/#graph), that might help clear things up

Comment: I've already seen the Graph. But where is the docs ?

Comment: @user: [Donut](http://stackoverflow.com/users/121493/) already posted a link to the docs. Here it is again: http://github.com/madrobby/vapor.js

Comment: I went to that link. the vapor.js file is 0KB. and there is nothing in it. The README just has a `<script src='vapor.js'></script>` But How to make an AJAX GET/POST request with it.  or how to specify the callback is not written anywhere.

Comment: Sadly, the answers to this question are completely useless.

Comment: @NeelBasu: vapor.js was a joke project to encourage people to learn javascript instead of depending on libraries like jQuery. So to make ajax request with vapor.js you'd use xmlHTTPrequest.

Comment: FWIW, for my own personal code where I prefer minimal use of libraries (meaning, none at all) I use the xmlHTTPrequest shim found on the wikipedia article for xmlHTTPrequest to make it cross-browser: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 1):

[microajax](http://code.google.com/p/microajax/) is what I settled on.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a library but it is a "Small Simple XMLHttp Wrapper" I made:

```
//params format:"bob=hi&id=1295&lol=haha"
function ajax_post(post_url,params,success_callback,fail_callback,timeout)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("POST",post_url, true);

    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    //xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 ) 
        {
            clearTimeout(xmlHttpTimeout); 
            if(xmlHttp.status == 200)
            {
                success_callback();
            }
            else 
            {
                    fail_callback();
            }
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.send(params);

    var xmlHttpTimeout=setTimeout(ajaxTimeout,timeout);
    function ajaxTimeout()
    {
       xmlHttp.abort();
       fail_callback();
    }

}

function ajax_get(url,success_callback,fail_callback,timeout)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url, true);

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 ) 
        {
            clearTimeout(xmlHttpTimeout); 
            if(xmlHttp.status == 200)
            {
                success_callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
            }
            else 
            {
                    fail_callback();
            }
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.send();

    var xmlHttpTimeout=setTimeout(ajaxTimeout,timeout);
    function ajaxTimeout()
    {
       xmlHttp.abort();
       fail_callback();
    }

}
```

Comment: Down-votes are acceptable, but please add a comment explaining your reasoning. Stack Exchange is a learning platform after all.

Answer (score 0):

Here' a small chunk of a JavaScript PHP wrapper I wrote a long time ago when I virtually knew nothing about JavaScript... it barely contains any AJAX methods, just wrapper functions that communicate with a PHP backend in order to allow PHP to do all the work...

In all honesty, to get what it seems you're looking for... just sit down and write yourself an AJAX library with all the common helper functions. It should take you a few hours at the most.

**The Javascript:**

```
(function() {

var
    PHPJS = window.PHPJS = window.$ = function() {
      return new PHPJS.Strings;
  };

PHPJS.Strings = PHPJS.prototype = {

    InitAJAX: function(Library, ServerString)
    {
        var ResultCache = document.body;
        var FunctionRequest;
        try {
            FunctionRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                FunctionRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    FunctionRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                    throw new Error("The XMLHttpRequest() object is not supported by your browser.")
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        FunctionRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (FunctionRequest.readyState == 4 && FunctionRequest.status == 200) {
                ResultCache.innerHTML = FunctionRequest.responseText;
                return FunctionRequest.responseText;
            }
        } 

        switch (Library) {
            case 'Arrays' :
            FunctionRequest.open("GET", "functions/arrays-lib.php" + ServerString, true);
            break;
            case 'Math' :
            FunctionRequest.open("GET", "functions/math-lib.php" + ServerString, true);
            break;
            case 'Strings' :
            FunctionRequest.open("GET", "functions/strings-lib.php" + ServerString, true);
            break;
        }
        FunctionRequest.send(null);
    },

    /* String Functions */
    addcslashes: function(str, charlist)
    {
        return this.InitAJAX('Strings','?function=addcslashes&String='+str+'&Charlist='+charlist);
    },
    addslashes: function(str)
    {
        return this.InitAJAX('Strings','?function=addslashes&String='+str);
    },
    bin2hex: function(str)
    {
        return this.InitAJAX('Strings','?function=bin2hex&String='+str);
    },
    chop: function(str,charlist)
    {
        return this.InitAJAX('Strings','?function=chop&String='+str+'&Charlist='+charlist);
    },
    chr: function(int)
    {
        return this.InitAJAX('Strings','?function=chr&Int='+int);
    },
    chunk_split: function(str, chunklen, end)
    {
        return this.InitAJAX('Strings','?function=chunk_split&String='+str+'&Chunklen='+chunklen+'&End='+end);
    },
    convert_cyr_string: function(str)
    {
        return this.InitAJAX('Strings','?function=convert_cyr_string');
    },

    /* more functions... */
}

})();

//PHPJS.bin2hex('afsdfadsafdsafdasfsaf');
```

**The PHP:**

```
<?php
switch($_GET['function']) {
    case 'addcslashes' :    
        $charlist = (@$_GET['Charlist']) ? ','.$_GET['Charlist'] : '';
        echo addcslashes($_GET['String'], $charlist);
    break;
    case 'addslashes' : 
        echo addslashes($_GET['String']);
    break;
    case 'bin2hex' :    
        echo bin2hex($_GET['String']);
    break;
    case 'chop' :   
        $charlist = (@$_GET['Charlist']) ? ','.$_GET['Charlist'] : '';
        echo rtrim($_GET['String'], $charlist);
    break;
    case 'chr' :
        echo chr($_GET['Int']);
    break;
    case 'chunk_split' :
        echo chunk_split($_GET['String'], @$_GET['Chunklen'], @$_GET['End']);
    break;
        /** ...etc, etc... **/
?>
```

Comment: This is not What I am looking for.